# admin-ajax returns an error: admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm facing an issue and I can't get the reason, I tried to print the variables and check for typo errors, But couldn't find any.

I send an Ajax request to admin-ajax:

```
function update_order() {
    var orderdata = {
        action: 'update_order_ajax',
        data: 'test'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
            if (currAjax != null) {
                currAjax.abort();

            }
            currAjax = jqXHR;
         },
         url: ajaxurl,
         data: orderdata,
         dataType: 'text',
         success: function (response) {
             alert(response);
         }

    }); //end Ajax

} //end function

//Run the above function on submitting a form.
jQuery('#updateOrder').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    update_order();
});
```

The files are inside a folder inside plugin folder "http://localhost/test/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/update-order/template"

Inside that folder I have:

```
function update_order_ajax() {
    echo $_POST['data']; //That should return 'test'
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_order_ajax', 'update_order_ajax' );
```

But I get:

```
POST http://localhost/test/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
```

I searched and viewed many related question and tried to use a custom URL for the `admin-ajax.php`, Also checked the errors file, But couldn't find any solution.

I checked the `admin-ajax.php` and I see that it returns `400`, When:

- `$_REQUEST['action']` is empty.
- `! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] )`
- `! has_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] )`

What is the problem?

Comment: If you trying as a non logged user you should use `wp_ajax_nopriv`

Comment: @mokiSRB, I'm logged in as admin, That's why I'm using `wp_ajax_`

Comment: try changing the data type or just comment that line out